# Delete doesn't happen until refresh

Tags: angular

So i made a small app that displayes a couple of diseases (it's still in its early stages).
For now, you can filter the diseases, add a new disease and delete a disease. I made it so that when you add a disease, you dont need to refresh the page to see the new disease in the list. I then tried to do the same thing with the delete function, but it doesn't actually change the list until you refresh the page. I found a solution somewhere but it still doesnt work. 
Below is my DataService code

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DiseaseDataService {
  private _diseases: Disease[];
  private _diseases$ = new BehaviorSubject<Disease[]>([]);


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.diseases$.subscribe((diseases: Disease[]) => {
      this._diseases = diseases;
      this._diseases$.next(this._diseases);
    });
  }
  get allDiseases$(): Observable<Disease[]> {
    return this._diseases$; 
  }
  get diseases$(): Observable<Disease[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/diseases/`).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError),
      tap(console.log),
      map(
        (list: any[]): Disease[] => list.map(Disease.fromJson)
      )
    );
  }
  addNewDisease(disease: Disease) {
    return this.http
      .post(`${environment.apiUrl}/diseases/`, disease.toJson())
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError), map(Disease.fromJson))
      .subscribe((dis: Disease) => {
        this._diseases = [...this._diseases, dis];
        this._diseases$.next(this._diseases);
      });

  }
  deleteDisease(disease: Disease) {
    return this.http
      .delete(`${environment.apiUrl}/diseases/${disease.id}`)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError), map(Disease.fromJson))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this._diseases = this._diseases.filter(dis => dis.id != disease.id)
        this._diseases$.next(this._diseases);
      })
  }
  handleError(err: any): Observable<never> {
    let errorMessage: string;
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      errorMessage = `'${err.status} ${err.statusText}' when accessing '${err.url}'`;
    } else {
      errorMessage = `an unknown error occured ${err}`;
    }
    console.log(err);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
  }

}
```

this._diseases = this._diseases.filter(dis => dis.id != disease.id)

this part in the deleteDisease method I found somewhere online, but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug a subscribe function, which should be fired after delete method call. Maybe delete method doesn't emit any values, so your filter function can't be reached.

Comment: @thijsheyndrickx try to console.log ```this._disease``` after assigning filtered array to it. Does it contains correct data? Deleted item is missing at it?

Comment: Yes this way i found it! The problem was with the map() fucntion. Removing it solved the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a change detection issue.

`*ngFor="let disease of diseases; trackBy: id"`

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf